# How to get the devexpress lookupedit display text from the corresponding edit value

Tags: c#, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

Hai all,

I want to get lookupedit display text when am giving correspond edit value.

example:
if am giving

```
LookupEdit1.Editvalue="3";
```

then it should show display text of `Editvalue="3"`

please help

//code

```
 cmbChemical.Properties.DataSource = _lab.selectChemicals();
        cmbChemical.Properties.DisplayMember = "labitem_Name";
        cmbChemical.Properties.ValueMember = "labItem_ID";
        cmbChemical.Properties.BestFitMode = BestFitMode.BestFit;
        cmbChemical.Properties.SearchMode = SearchMode.AutoComplete;

        cmbChemical.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("labitem_Name", 100,  "Chemicals"));
    cmbChemical.Properties.AutoSearchColumnIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, at least not in the way you're trying. The `LookUpEdit`, as the name implies, looks up its values in a `DataSource`, eg. a collection of objects. Therefore, to display the value `3` you need to have a list of objects that contains this value and set it as a `DataSource` for the control.

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("3");
lookUpEdit.Properties.DataSource = values;
lookUpEdit.EditValue = "3";
```

Maybe if you specify what are you trying to do, we can help you achieve that.

Comment: post your entire scenario, what are you binding to that lookupedit and why do you need it to display the value `3`

Comment: Problem is that,  am already bind both display member and value member of lookupedit, when i give edit value =3 or something then correspond text should be selected in the lookpedit. please help

Comment: Are you binding on a `DataTable`? If yes, can you post the structure?

Comment: s am using datatable contain labitem_Name,labItem_ID   .
I given code above with my question

Comment: it might be something with `labitem_ID` datatype. if it's int you should give it the value 3 as int not string.

Comment: I given as you told.but editvalue is not changing.It always shows  initial edit value given through property window

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to specify  display member or value member to get your needed behaviour. Following code give me a form with the lookupedit correctly showing "4", and i can choose other values from the list too.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {

        var lookUpEdit1 = new LookUpEdit();
        Controls.Add(lookUpEdit1);

        var source = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
            source.Add(i.ToString());
        lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = source;
        lookUpEdit1.EditValue = "4";
    }

}
```

Maybe you get wrong results because you set  display member and value member of the control.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me.

```
private void lookUpEdit1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((e.OriginalSource as SLTextBox).Text);
    }
}
```